# jQuery Sortable Cannot Click After Sort Issue

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a table that is being sorted by the TR tags, everything works fine except that I have to click twice on any item in the list after something has been moved for anything to respond, on links etc. Do I have to call some function after the list has been sorted to re-activate it so that I don't have to click twice on items?

Answer (score 1):

Can't truly understand the issue without code samples but if you believe that refreshing could solve it you probably need `.sortable('refresh');`